# BatchSave is failing with No insertions even if I have one failed Batch item in return

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

We have a data of 200 records which we are trying to insert to Dynamo DB using batchSave.

There are 10 duplicate data which is throwed back in List and we are capturing this data in a collection to correct and reprocess.

But my question here is It should have inserted the rest 190 records but that is not happening. Is this expected behaviour with batchSave ?

Code Snippets

```html
DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper = awsSdkClientFactory.getDynamoDBMapper();


public List<Map<String, AttributeValue>> batchSaveItems(List<EmployeeData> employeeData) {
        List<DynamoDBMapper.FailedBatch> result = dynamoDBMapper.batchSave(employeeData);
        return dynamoHelper.handleUnprocessed(dynamoDBMapper, tableName, result);
    }

public List<Map<String, AttributeValue>> handleUnprocessed(DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper, String tableName, List<DynamoDBMapper.FailedBatch> result) {
        List<Map<String, AttributeValue>> attrValueMapList = new ArrayList<>();

        if (CollectionUtils.isNullOrEmpty(result)) {
            return attrValueMapList;
        }

        threadWrapper.sleep(RETRY_WAIT_TIME);

        for (DynamoDBMapper.FailedBatch failedBatch : result) {
            List<EmployeeData> failedEmployeeData = getFailedBatchListItems(dynamoDBMapper, failedBatch);
            List<DynamoDBMapper.FailedBatch> secondResult = dynamoDBMapper.batchSave(failedEmployeeData );

            if (!secondResult.isEmpty()) {
                logger.error(getClass(), String.format("Failed to write %s items on second attempt.", secondResult.size()));
                attrValueMapList.addAll(getItems(tableName, secondResult));
            }
        }

        return attrValueMapList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't show how you handle failed batches. If more than 2 items have the same key within a batch (duplicates) DynamoDB will fail the entire batch. Ensure you are catch SDK exception and also handling unprocessed items:

#### SDK Error

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Programming.Errors.html

#### Unprocessed items

```
private List<T> getFailedBatchListItems(final FailedBatch failedBatch, final Class<T> clazz) {
    return failedBatch.getUnprocessedItems()
                      .values()
                      .stream()
                      .flatMap(List::stream)
                      .map(WriteRequest::getPutRequest)
                      .map(PutRequest::getItem)
                      .map(e -> dynamoDBMapper.marshallIntoObject(clazz, e))
                      .collect(toList());
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Leeroy Hannigan,    Yes, we are processing failed batch but that is giving only failed 10 records but not the rest. That is what concerning me on how to save these 190 records which are kind of good.  Main issue over here is I want to send these failed records back to producer. I cannot reprocess them to insert again. Having said that I need to get the good records inserted to DB.

Comment: Can you show more of your code? How are you handling failed records. How are you handling SDK errors?

Comment: I updated more code in description. Appreciate your time. THnaks